# socket.emit() is emitting multiple times to the server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io

i trying to create a chat-app using socket.io in my project, in which i'm emitting the message from client side to server side through click handler. The function is running only once but it is emitting message several times.
here is the code:

**adminMessageContent.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  useCreateOrGetMessage,
  useUpdateMessage,
} from "../../../hooks/chatHooks/chatHooks";
import { socket } from "../../../socket/socket";

import { format } from "timeago.js";
import { useQueryClient } from "react-query";

const AdminMsgContent = (props) => {
  const { chatId: id } = props;
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState();
  const scrollRef = useRef();

  const { isLoading, data } = useCreateOrGetMessage(id);
  const adminId = localStorage.getItem("adminId");
  //   console.log(data);
  const { mutate: updateMsg } = useUpdateMessage();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const sender = true;
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [updateMsg, data]);

  const handleSend = () => {
    const objMsg = { chatId: id, sender: sender, message: msg };
    updateMsg(objMsg);
    socket.emit("sendMessage", {
      message: msg,
    });
    setMsg("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventHandler = ({ msg, chatId }) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(["message", chatId]);
      console.log(chatId);
      console.log(msg);
    };
    socket.on(`${id}`, eventHandler);
    return () => {
      socket.off(`${id}`, eventHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const receiverId = data?.data.chatId.members.find((i) => i !== adminId);
    if (receiverId) {
      socket.emit("adduser", {
        // senderId: adminId,
        receiverId: receiverId,
        chatId: id,
      });
    }
  }, [data]);

  if (isLoading && id) {
    return <div className="admin-chat-chat">Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="admin-chat-messages">
        {data.data.conversation.map((i) => (
          <>
            {i.sender === false ? (
              <>
                <div className="left-message displaysender" ref={scrollRef}>
                  {i.message}
                </div>

                <div className="left-message" style={{ fontSize: "x-small" }}>
                  {format(i.createdAt)}
                </div>
                {/* </div> */}
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <div className="right-message displayreceiver" ref={scrollRef}>
                  {i.message}
                </div>
                <div className="right-message" style={{ fontSize: "x-small" }}>
                  {format(i.createdAt)}
                </div>
              </>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="admin-chat-input">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Type your message..."
          value={msg}
          onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => handleSend()}>Send</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AdminMsgContent;
```

**app.js**

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Connected", socket.id);

  
  socket.on("adduser", ({ receiverId, chatId }) => {
    console.log("chatId", chatId);
    console.log("receiverId", receiverId);
    if (!io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(`${chatId}`)) {
      socket.join(`${chatId}`);
    }
    socket.once("sendMessage", (msg) => {
      
      console.log(msg);
      io.sockets.in(`${chatId}`).emit(`${chatId}`, { msg, chatId });
    });
  });


  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user Disconnected", socket.id);
    removeUser(socket.id);
  });
});
```

I have looked through solutions and found that on server side instead of socket.on socket.once should be used but still it is emitting multiple times.

Comment: Do you know `useState()`'s behaviour

Comment: You are adding the event listener for the "sendMessage" event inside the handleSend function. It means that every time the handleSend function is called whenever the "Send" button is clicked, a new event listener is added, leading to multiple event listeners over time. You should move the event listener registration outside the handleSend function.

Comment: can you suggest a way for moving the  event listener registration outside the handleSend function @Akeel Ahmed Qureshi